# Allow control to grow, but not to shrink

Tags: c#, wpf

I basically have a setup like this:

```
<GroupBox>
  <TextBlock Name="tbValue"/>
</GroupBox>
```

The content of the TextBlock changes very often (displaying a measure value from a sensor). This leads to the width of the groupbox changing all the time which looks&feels like crap.

Does anyone have an idea how i could make the groupbox grow automatically when the text changes, but not shink again whenever the text gets shorter again?

Comment: Can you not just set a minimum width?

Comment: I could, but that would result in a lot of whitespace, which looks ugly. User can also change the unit in which the values are presented, everything is very flexible, so i would prefer a more generic way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just handle the [`SizeChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event and set the `GroupBox`'s [`MinWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.minwidth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to the largest between the `MinWidth` and the [`ActualWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<GroupBox SizeChanged="GroupBox_SizeChanged">
    <TextBlock Name="tbValue"/>  
</GroupBox>
```

Code behind:

```
private void GroupBox_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var gb = sender as GroupBox;
    gb.MinWidth = Math.Max(gb.MinWidth, gb.ActualWidth);
}
```

Comment: The problem with something like this is that you're using the ActualWidth which is what it was arranged at and which may be well above the desized width. For example if the control were docked to the bottom or top of the window it would get wider as the window did but with this if you tried making the window smaller the groupbox would stay that large size. I would think that you might need to derive an element (e.g. from Decorator) and deal with this in the measure based on the desired size of the contained child.

Comment: @AndrewS this is enough to meet the OP's requirement. I'm pretty sure the `GroupBox` is set to stretch to the `TextBlock`'s Width.

Comment: That totally fits my requirements! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Can propose behavior. Raw sample

```
public class GrowOnlyWidthBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
    }

    private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        AssociatedObject.MinWidth = Math.Max(AssociatedObject.MinWidth, AssociatedObject.ActualWidth);
    }
}
```

Updated behavior. Thanks to **AndrewS** for pointing to the error in previous code. I used logic from **HighCore**'s answer.

Comment: Does this actually work? I mean SizeChanged is a notification event - it is called from the OnRenderSizeChanged method of UIElement which is called from UpdateLayout after the measure/arrange are complete. Handled is only on the args because it derives from RoutedEventArgs.

Comment: but +1 for the idea of using an attached property/behaviour! thanks!

Comment: @AndrewS thank you very much for your note. JCH2k, I've updated my code so it works properly. Now it's the mix of my code and of HighCore